# How can I save a dendrogram plot from scipy.cluster.hierarchy dendrogram as a file?

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

As I am doing agglomerative clustering, I would like to retain the dendrograms rendered for later review.

As far as I can see, scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram() function does not return a matlplotlib figure object that can be saved.  What would be the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

Found out that I could just catch the current figure with

```
matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
```

and save it with

```
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(filename)
```